# how to include ACRA in ProGuard rule file

Tags: proguard, acra

i am configuring ProGuard for the entire Project.

When i try to run the App .apk file got generted successfully.
I  get following exception in the line of ACRA initialization.

```
        java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PUT
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:243)
        at cjw.a(SourceFile:124)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Proguard config to make sure it includes that outlined at:
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Proguard

And if that doesn't fix it then post

- your ACRA config
- your Proguard config